# scheduled queue property in Python SDK for Service Bus Queue

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

We are using Azure service bus in our development where we need to use a schedulequeue property of service bus. We found how to use implement it using C# but, how do we use the property in Python SDK for Service Bus Queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation:

- [Broker Properties and User Properties](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicebus.html#broker-properties-and-user-properties)

> This section describes how to use Broker and User properties defined here: [Message Headers and Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/servicebus/message-headers-and-properties)

```
sent_msg = Message(b'This is the third message',
               broker_properties={'Label': 'M3'},
               custom_properties={'Priority': 'Medium',
                                  'Customer': 'ABC'}
       )
```

In the referenced link, you can find the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property of the brokered message, so you can set it like that:

```
sent_msg = Message(b'This is the third message',
               broker_properties={'ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc': datetime(2011, 12, 14)}
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

In the v7 https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/#description
, we have a kwarg for the scheduled enqueue time

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusMessage

ServiceBusMessage(object, scheduled_enqueue_time_utc=datetime(2011, 12, 14))
```